# how to iterate a unordered map from begin to a certain index not end

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a unordered map of size 5 but I want to run a for loop for index 0 to index 1 then what should be the syntax? I tried this but such error is coming.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ6S5.jpg)

Comment: Please post code and output, not images.
That said, you will need to take your `begin()` iterator and advance that by your index to get your 'end'. Alternatively, just use an indexed for loop.

Comment: You can't sort an `unordered_map`.

Comment: You appear to be trying to use `std::sort` on an `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe (without having looked at the images) and just going from your description, this code might do what you want.

```
int targetIndex = 1;
auto it = yourMap.begin();
for (int i = 0; i < targetIndex; ++i, ++it)
{
    //Do stuff to your iterator
}
```

Alternatively:

```
int targetIndex = 1;
auto end = yourMap.begin();
std::advance(end, targetIndex);
for (auto it = yourMap.begin(); it != end; ++it)
{
    //Do stuff to your iterator
}
```

Of course both these snippets assume, that your targetIndex is smaller than the mapSize.

On a side note, these approaches will work the same on any std container.

Answer (score -1):

This code might help you with your problem.

```
unorderd_map <string,int> m;
m["hh"]=10;
m["gg"]=20;
m["ff"]=30;
m["jj"]=40;
m["kk"]=50;

for(auto it=m.begin(); it!=m.end() ;it++)
{
       cout<<(*it).first<<" "<<(*it).second<<endl;    //cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second;
}
```

**The output of the program will be**

hh 10

gg 20

ff 30

jj 40

kk 50

Comment: The question asks how to iterate to a position **not** the `end()` of the container.